# Line 79: Using class 'Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter' that is non API on version '2.4.6-p1'

Tags: magento

Line 79: Using class 'Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter' that is non API on version '2.4.6-p1'
How to fix this error? Upgrade Compatibility Tool showing this errors.

checking vendor files but in vendor working it's working fine but in custom module it's show error.
could you please help me to fix this error?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9KcQ.png)